# SQL Server Convert Columns to Rows with a particular Format for Days of the Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Store data in SQL Server as below that has Store Opening Hours for each Day of the Week. We have roughly 1000 stores. Here is how sample data is stored.

[image: Current SQL Data Image]

Now I want to generate the data in this Format.

[image: New Data Format Image]

Here is the base query:

```
select StoreId, SqlDayOfWeek, Closed, TimeOpen, TimeClosed 
from StoreHours
```

Can you please help me with the query on the format that I mentioned.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select StoreID
      ,Schedule = stuff((Select concat('_'
                                      ,choose(SQLDayOfWeek,'Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat')+','
                                      ,IIF(Closed=1,'Closed',format(convert(datetime,TimeOpen),'HHmm')+',')
                                      ,IIF(Closed=1,'',format(convert(datetime,TimeClosed),'HHmm'))
                                      )
                          From  YourTable 
                          Where StoreID=A.StoreID 
                          Order By [SQLDayOfWeek]
                          For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') +';'
 From (Select Distinct StoreID from YourTable) A
 Group By StoreID
 Order By StoreID
```

**Returns**

Comment: Thank you @John Cappelletti.d. I tweaked little bit to what i wanted. But it worked Perfect.

Comment: @user8067273 Happy it helped  :)